# Discrete Math and Well ordered sets

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For my assignment they ask us the questions below.

```
a.  True or False: The set of natural numbers is a well-ordered set.
True

b.  True or False: The set of integers is a well-ordered set.

False

c.  True or False: The set of positive real numbers is a well-ordered set.

False
```

A well-ordered set has to have a least element. This being said, A has a least element.
For B i think it is not well-ordered because there is not a least element that i can see
For C I think it is false but would it not be true because we confine it to just positive real numbers?

If i am wrong can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: This reasoning looks correct to me. For (c), note that there is no lowest positive real number.

Comment: You know what you are right! I forgot what exactly a real number was for a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) it’s not enough that $\Bbb N$ has a least element: $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered because every non-empty subset of $\Bbb N$ has a least element. The let of non-negative real numbers has a least element, $0$, but it’s not well ordered, because (for instance) the set of positive real numbers, which is a non-empty subset of it, does not have a least element.

Your reasoning for (b) is fine.